# How to get xAxis and yAxis information on a Highcharts heatmap click event?

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

In a Highcharts heatmap, I define a click event as usually:

```
options.plotOptions = {
    series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function() {
                /* action */
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

How can I get the xAxis and yAxis information in this function?

For example, in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/3UWaA/3/) demo, when I click 0.67 at the top left conner, I want to alert "Friday, Alexander".

Can I pass arguments to this function? Or is there any other approach?

Thanks! : )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The event has the point attached to it.  So, you can do something like this:

```
           click: function (event) {
                var str = event.point.series.yAxis.categories[event.point.y] + ',' +
                    event.point.series.xAxis.categories[event.point.x]
                alert(str);
            }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/blaird/3UWaA/26/